# ?: unexpected behaviour - although condition is true, the ? part is not executed

Tags: c, if-statement, operators

Consider this code:

```
// Example program
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum{
  enum_1,
  enum_2
}my_enum;
/* 
 * this is not how the function works but when I debug 
 * it will always returns enum_1 (verified when using the debugger)
 * so I hope this is enough
 */    
int fun_1(int arg_1){return enum_1;} 
const int const_1 = 10;
const int const_2 = 20;
int main()
{
    int arg_1 = 0;

    int var_1 = fun_1(arg_1);

    int var_2 = (var_1 == (enum_1 
                    || enum_2))
                    ? const_1*10     // I expect this result
                    : const_2*10;    // instead I get this. why?
    printf("%d\n" , var_2);

    if(var_1==enum_1)
        var_2 = const_1*10;          // here it works fine        
    printf("%d\n" , var_2);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm debugging this code, and var_1 is expected to get the value of enum_1. It does, but somehow the "? :" operator does not give me the expected result - it does not assign `const_1*10` to `var_2` but `const_2*10`. When I move along in the debug and go to the if statement I get the expected result. Why is that?

I'm using windriver workbench on windows 8.1

**EDIT**

I changed the example to a runnable version, and as mentioned by tkausl, the problem was using `(var_1 == (enum_1 || enum_2))` instead of `(var_1 == enum_1 ||  var_1 == enum_2))`

Comment: You mind creating an [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: `(enum_1 || enum_2)` produces a bool.

Comment: your comparison is wrong. check @tkausl 's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not comparing `var_1` to `enum_1`, neither to `enum_2` but to `(enum_1 || enum_2)`, you probably want `(var_1 == enum_1 || var_1 == enum_2)`

Comment: oh... (enum_1 || enum_2) will result in 1 because it is true?

Comment: Yes, if one of both enums is non-zero then this will always be 1.

Answer (score 1):

`enum1` is 0, and `enum2` is 1 (the defaults if you don't explicitly specify the enum values).

`So (var_1 == (enum_1 || enum_2))` evaluates to

`(0 == (0 || 1))` which is equivalent to

`(0 == 1)` which is 0.

So the expression evaluates to the second part of the ternary, as you observe.

Did you want `var_1 == enum_1 || var_1 == enum_2`?

Answer (score 1):

```
var_1 == (enum_1 
                || enum_2)
```

`enum_1` is probably implemented as 0, `enum_2` as 1. Thus

```
(enum_1 || enum_2)
```

is basically (`#include <stdbool.h>` for readability)

```
(false || true)
```

and thus `true`, which is - as integer - represented as `1`. So

```
var_1 == 1
```

with `var_1` having the value `enum_1` (which is probably 0) is **false**.

You want

```
(var_1 == enum_1) || (var_1 == enum_2)
```

as condition.

Comment: "is probably implemented". Actually is **definitely** implemented.

Comment: @Bathsheba If the header (and the enum definition) is really written that way, then yes. I prefer keeping it generic, as above reasoning also holds if they've different values associated.

Comment: @Bathsheba in this example it is definitely implemented as 0 and 1, but this is just an example. in my real code, both of the enums I use are bigger than 0 so it would be implemented as (true || true) as Daniel suspected

Comment: Formally it's 1 || 1 in C - in `int` types, (and true | true in C++).